# Powershell Access to Path is Denied

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, powershell-3.0, githooks

I have developed a git pre-commit hook for my workplace. The way it operates is as follows:

There is a pre-commit file that invokes a pre-commit.ps1 file in the same directory. Both are withing the .git/hooks/ folder

The pre-commit.ps1 file is used to identify some regular expressions to ensure that any files committed do not have any identifiers specific to my workplace.

The setup works perfectly for me. However, I have tried testing on a colleagues laptop and she is getting the following error when trying to commit:

```
Access to the path is denied. + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here is the code in th pre-commit file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get the directory where the script is located

HOOK_DIR=$(dirname "$0")

# Use 'which' to find the PowerShell executable in the PATH

POWERSHELL_PATH=$(which powershell.exe || which pwsh)

# Check if PowerShell was found

if [ -z "$POWERSHELL_PATH" ]; then

    echo "PowerShell not found in PATH"

    exit 1

fi

# Invoke the PowerShell script using the dynamically found path

"$POWERSHELL_PATH" -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -File "$HOOK_DIR/pre-commit.ps1"
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is, specially since I can run the setup perfectly well, but my colleague cannot.

For testing, we simplified the pre-commit.ps1 file to only print a statement such as:

```
Write-Host "Hello"
```

However, she is still getting the same error - so we concluded that the issue must be with the invocation of PowerShell in the pre-commit file.

I have also confirmed:

1. She has powershell installed
2. Her `Get-ExecutionPolicy` is the same as mine, set to "Bypass"
3. However, her starting directory on a PowerShell terminal is different to mine. Mine starts at H:, whereas hers starts at C:\Windows\System32\ (not sure if this relevant or I'm missing something).

Comment: Are you using a different bash/cmd? Are any PS scripts invokeable on your college's system?

Comment: @wp78de our test using the Write-Host "Hello" yielded the same error. Not sure if I am using a different bash/cmd but it is unlikely.

Comment: @mklement0 how do you mean? this is the full error:
Access to the path is denied. + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: That said, an attempt to _execute a script file_ that is located inside an inaccessible-due-to-lack-of-permissions directory usually triggers a fundamentally _different_ error, namely `The term 'c:\path\to\inaccessible\dir\script.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: @mklement0 the full error I get when I try to run my pre-commit script is the one i posted in the OP. I do get a similar error to yours when I try to run the following:
`get-command powershell.exe,pwsh| select Name,Source`

Here is the first part of the error:
`get-command: The term 'pwsh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: I missed that your original error is ultimately of type `CommandNotFoundException`, which is mysterious. The `get-command powershell.exe,pwsh| select Name,Source` output is expected. After the original error occurs, does `$Error[0] | Format-List * -Force` provide additional clues?

Comment: The original error suggests a weird combination of PowerShell finding an executable but not being able to invoke it due to lack of permissions. Does the `.ps1` script ensure that it targets `.git/hooks/` _in the same directory as the script (`(Join-Path $PSScriptRoot .git/hooks/)`) ? If not, then the working directory does matter.

Comment: @mklement0 if it was a directory or path issue i'd be expecting to get the same error as well? i'm starting to think its a permission or execution issue for her PS since her PS starts in the C:\Windows\System32\ path

Comment: @aishraq, yes, that is unusual: `C:\Windows\System32` should only be the startup directory in _elevated_ (run as admin) sessions; otherwise, it should be the user's profile directory.